# I am applying for PhD in math and have to choose which courses to take for the Spring

Tags: mathematics, coursework

Im new to this forum and have a question. I am a junior in math major applying for pure math PhD and struggle choosing between two courses.

1. Probability Theory

This is the subject I'm pretty excited about and want to learn more about. And it will cover higher math stuff involving measure theory etc and I heard the professor is awesome. The issue is that I already took the course that has the same course name(albeit, of course they have different course number) from statistics department, which focuses on more application side, i.e. more easy going, in which I got a good grade. So for application for PhD in math I fear that it looks just weird for the people reviewing my transcript.

2. partial differential eqiation

Im not so excited about this subject and in fact I read a book by Strauss with graduate student over the Fall in reading program in my school, and I will write it in my resume. But I know that this subject is pretty standard for math major and probably have to skip it if I don't take it now. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: To study applied math, statistics will be (more) useful. For pure math, probably PDE. But this is a personal choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I advise doing what excites you the most.

As you point out, the focus of the probability course in the math department is more theoretical than the one you had in statistics, so will contribute to your preparation for a pure math doctorate.

I don't think you have to worry about the fact that the courses have the same name. You can clear this up with a sentence in your cover letter.